# Database Design for Multiple Store/Warehouse

Tags: sql, database-design

Please notice that I've checked and I am pretty sure you that this Q is not among the already answered questions.

Actually, I need an example of a database that is hosting multiple stores (warehouses) and allows you to:

- know where the purchased items are stored (e.g. in which warehouse)
- know how many items you have available
- know how many items have been sold and from where 
  etc. etc.

I am not looking for a specific DB engine (MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle etc.)

Thank you so much

Comment: I removed all those dbms tags, since you're not looking for a specific DB engine...

Comment: well OK but they all can be of help as all of those are familiar with the design. Meaning this is not only sql but however you guys pretend that you know everything so what can i do? Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for a hosting service? Or are you going to design the db and write the code?

Comment: I need an example as i found this multiple warehouses DESIGN extremely confusing. Meaning i do not need a hosting. Thank you

Comment: Can you show us your current design attempt?

Comment: Nah it's a very basic design having Order table with Qty column that i update when a new item is purchased or sold. Beside the fact that it's very hard to maintain, it's also impossible to know in which warehouse an item is currently etc. etc.

Comment: We can assist you, but we wont do the work for you.

Comment: I am not looking for anyone to work for me... i just need an example or a suggestion. For instance if i have had an example from an old project that matches what i am looking for, i would give a screenshot to the guy who needs a help. Sorry if i wasn't clear anough

Comment: I removed the data-warehouse tag, as that is not what you think it is. Your question is too general, but if you already have one transactional table and you cannot identify which warehouse the transaction is for, then you need to create a table containing a master list of warehouses, and the primary key of that table needs to be stored in your transaction table. But my best advice is that you should probably pay someone to do this

Comment: OK i will pay someone if i knew where to find someone who knows to design that DB in a way i need to. However i noticed that you again edited tags to SQL. Please notice that i don't need SQL help but rather DBA help. SQL is a scripting language which in my case doesn't suit at all. However thank you for your tips in the previous comment. It's much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: An administrator (DBA) doesn't normally do a lot of database design work (which it appears what you are after) Anyway I found this page for you: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/ which yielded this example data model: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/oil_companies/warehouse_deliveries_subject_area.htm

Comment: This one might be even better: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/tracking_customer_shipments/index.htm